# @DocumentID Firestore using Swift Codable

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, codable

When coding up a struct that is Codable, we are told we should use

```
@DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
```

However, the id is not the same as the id shown in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution today.  Turns out that if you remove the

```
= UUID().uuidString
```

from the property and add the id to the CodingKey enum

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
```

You then get back the id as it shows in the console!